# Dimension of kernel for nilpotent transformation powers

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, linear-transformations, nilpotence

Let $T:\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^n$ be a nilpotent transformation with index $n$. (i.e. $T^n=0$). Is it true that for all $n≥k≥0$, $\dim \ker T^k=k$? How can that be shown?

The context is a linear algebra text book and it is the chapter about Jordan canonical forms so I guess it is related. I tried playing around with that - but no luck.

Comment: When you say that the index is $n$, do you mean that $T^k \neq 0$ for $k < n$?

Comment: If so, then yes: your statement is correct.  Do you know anything about "Jordan canonical form"?

Comment: Also, it might be helpful if you provided context: how did you come across this problem?  Did you have any thoughts on how to approach it?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom yes for the first comment

Comment: Can you show how you tried to solve this problem.

Comment: The context is a linear algebra text book and it is the chapter about Jordan canonical forms so I guess it is related. I tried playing around with that - but no luck

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is yes.  To see that this is the case, make the following observations:

- $\dim \ker T = 1$
- $\ker T^k = (\ker T \cap \operatorname{image}(T^{k-1}))+ \ker T^{k-1}$
- $\operatorname{image}(T^{k}) \subset \operatorname{image}(T^{k-1})$

See if you can put these facts together

Comment: I have shown that $dim Ker T >= 1$, how can I show equality?

Comment: Show that we must have $\dim \ker T^{k+1} > \dim \ker T^{k}$ for each $k$ (otherwise, we can't have $T^n = 0$).